# Apply for loop or sapply on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have data like wherein A* represents the place with time format (01:01) as column names and the row names like 1C or 9D represent the individual ID.

```
structure(list(V1 = c("1C", "9D", "9F", "9H", "9S", "9T", "9Y"
), `A*01:01` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `A*02:01` = c(NA, 
NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `A*02:02` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `A*02:03` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `A*02:05` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*02:06` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*03:01` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `A*11:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*11:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*23:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `A*23:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `A*24:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", 
NA, NA), `A*24:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `A*25:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*26:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*29:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), `A*29:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), `A*30:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", 
NA, NA), `A*30:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `A*31:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), `A*32:01` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `A*33:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), `A*33:03` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), `A*34:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*34:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*36:01` = c(NA, 
NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `A*43:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*66:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*66:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*68:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `A*68:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*69:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `A*74:01` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `A*80:01` = c(NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `B*07:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*07:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*08:01` = c(NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `B*13:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*13:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*14:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*14:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*14:05` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*14:06` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*15:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:10` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*15:12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:13` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*15:16` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*15:18` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*18:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*27:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA), `B*27:05` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*27:08` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*35:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*35:08` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*37:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*38:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*39:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*39:05` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*40:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA), `B*40:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*40:05` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*40:06` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA), `B*41:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*41:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*42:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*44:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*44:03` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*45:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA), `B*46:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*47:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*48:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*49:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*50:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA), `B*51:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*51:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*52:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*53:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*54:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*55:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*56:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*57:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*57:03` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*58:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*59:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*67:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*73:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, NA), `B*78:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*81:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `B*82:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `B*82:02` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*01:02` = c("1", 
NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA), `C*02:02` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "1"), `C*02:10` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*03:02` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*03:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `C*03:04` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*04:01` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `C*04:03` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"1"), `C*05:01` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*06:02` = c("1", 
"1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C*07:01` = c("1", "1", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `C*07:02` = c("1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C*07:04` = c("1", 
"1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C*08:01` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "1"), `C*08:02` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*12:02` = c("1", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*12:03` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "1"), `C*14:02` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA), `C*15:02` = c("1", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*16:01` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "1"), `C*17:01` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1"), `C*18:01` = c("1", 
"1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C*18:02` = c("1", "1", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c("1C", "9D", "9F", "9H", "9S", "9T", "9Y"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using the following code to process the data, which is working fine for column 2. But I have 16000 columns and 400 rows in my real data. I want to use "for loop" or "sapply" in R to perform processing. A quick solution is much appreciated.

```
LA <- dat[!is.na(dat[,2]),]
LA<-LA[,1]
res <- gsub("[[:digit:]]","",LA)
pos <- gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",LA)
LA_sep <- data.frame(res, pos)
LA_sep$res <- paste0(LA_sep$res, "&")
LA_sep$pos <- paste0(LA_sep$pos, "&")
LA_sep <- as.data.frame(t(LA_sep))
LA_sep <- apply(LA_sep[1:ncol(LA_sep)], 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = "")) ## nrow(ma) ## ncol(ma) ## NCOL(1:12) ## NROW(1:12)
write.csv(LA_sep, "2.csv")
```

When I run the above code on big data, I got the following output for 2nd column (A*01:01). First I want to extract the  column V1 values where column 2, 3, 4 .. and so on having values 1 for each rows. Then split the digits and characters and saved as "res" and "pos" seprated by "&" for each row having value 1 for each columns (A*01:01, A*02:01, A02:02, ......)

res F&K&M&Q&E&R&A&R&N&A&N&N&H&N&M&H&S&A&N&T&N&N&G&T&G&T&T&TL&D&I&I&Y&F&R&D&M&I&K&K&R&A&H&H&A&H&A&R&R&R&G&D&G&P&I&E&L

pos 9&44&45&62&63&65&69&65&66&69&66&66&70&66&67&70&71&76&77&80&77&77&79&80&79&80&80&80&81&90&95&97&99&109&114&116&138&142&144&144&145&149&151&151&152&151&152&156&163&163&167&166&167&193&194&275&276

So, it is very difficult to do this for each column manually or without a loop for big data. Every output should be saved as column names as a separate file.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do with these data? Do you have to have the data in this structure? Given the steps you have provided so far, there may be much better ways to go about processing these data. Could you add a bit more detail on what you want the final output to be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have explained my best. Please have a look and reply.